# Application Icon(57*57) and Large icon(512*512) it should be same picture?

Tags: iphone, app-store

so wonder is it need to be the same picture?

it can use difference picture ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Edited) 
In [link text](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) stated:

> When you submit your application, you
>   must include a 512 x 512 pixel version
>   of your application icon for display
>   in the App Store. Although it’s
>   important that this version be
>   instantly recognizable as your
>   application icon, it should be subtly
>   richer and more detailed. In other
>   words, you should not simply scale up
>   your application icon to create an
>   icon for the App Store.

So I think from this follows that you can make **cosmetic** changes to your picture to make it look better in good resolution.
In our app we do the reverse thing - we create 512x512 artwork and use its scaled to 57x57 variant as application icon.

Comment: To further your answer: The large icon should have the same subject, colors and layout as the small icon, only with more detail.